# errors/exceptions accumulating design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, exception

A method returns some result, making a number of "attempts" to build it. The first attempt that succeeds should return. If none of them succeed an exception should be thrown:

```
class Calculator {
  public String calculate() throws Exception {
    // how do design it?
  }
  private String attempt1() throws Exception {
    // try to calculate and throw if fails
  }
  private String attempt2() throws Exception {
    // try to calculate and throw if fails
  }
  private String attempt3() throws Exception {
    // try to calculate and throw if fails
  }
}
```

It's important to mention that the exception thrown by `calculate` should preserve stack traces of all other exceptions thrown by private methods. How would you recommend to design `calculate()` method, with extendability and maintainability in mind?

Answer (score 2):

I would use Composite and Command.

```
interface CalculateCommand {
     public void calculate(CalculateContext context);
}
```

Now create an implementation for each attempt you want.

Next create a CompositeCommand -- here is an outline (you will need to fill in the blanks)

```
public class CompositeCalculateCommand implements CalculateCommand {

    CompositeCalculateCommand(List<CompositeCommand> commands) {
        this.commands = commands; // define this as a field
    }

    public void calculate(CommandContext context) {
         for (CalculateCommand command : commands) {
               try {
                   command.calculate(context);
               } catch(RuntimeException e) {
                   this.exceptions.add(e) // initialize a list to hold exceptions
               }
               if (context.hasResult) return; // break
         }
         // throw here. You didn't success since you never saw a success in your context.  You have a list of all exceptions.
    }

}
```

finally use it like

```
CalculateCommand allCommands = new CompositeCalculateCommand(someListOfCommands);
allCommands.calculate(someContextThatYouDefine);
// results now on context.
```

Note each command implementation is testable on its own, so this is very maintainable.  If you need to add calculations, you simply define a new type of `CalculateCommand`, so this is extensible.  It will also play well with dependency injection.  Note I define a CommandContext object so different commands can take different types of stuff (put in a context).